# Marker clusterer doesn't refresh after submit button

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

I'm developing a page in which there are two sections: the right section there is a map and in the left section there a form from which, when a submit button is pressed, draw several markers into the map (the coordinates are taken from a database). Whenever I press the submit button all the markers are deleted and then they are redrawn depending on the data gathered. In this page I'm also using the `MarkerClusterer`. The problem I'm experiencing is that the markers are deleted correctly but the `MarkerClusterer` remains in the map, overlapping.

Here is the function I've written which delete the markers:

```
function removeAllMarkers(){
      for(i = 0; i < markers.length; i++){
          markers[i].setMap(null);
      }

      markers.length = 0;
}
```

Here is the function that update the markers when the submit button is pressed:

```
function updateMarkers(dataMarkers){
                removeAllMarkers();

                for (i = 0; i < dataMarkers.length; i++) {
                    bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(dataMarkers[i].latitude, dataMarkers[i].longitude));

                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(dataMarkers[i].latitude, dataMarkers[i].longitude),
                        map: map,
                        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                        //icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage(icon)
                    });

                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                        return function() {
                            infowindow.setContent("<b>" + dataMarkers[i].name + "</b>" + "<br/> " 
                                                  + dataMarkers[i].street + "<br/> " 
                                                  + dataMarkers[i].code + " " + "<br/> "
                                                  + dataMarkers[i].city + " " + "<br/> "  
                                                  + dataMarkers[i].country);
                            infowindow.open(map, marker);
                        }
                    })(marker, i));


                    markers.push(marker);
                  }
                  // Fit these bounds to the map
                  map.fitBounds(bounds);

                  clusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
            }
```

The `MarkerClusterer` library is imported like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer.js"></script>
```

Where am I doing wrong? Thanks!!

Comment: Is `markers` a global array? Also, instead of forcing `markers.length = 0;` You should just set `markers = [];`

Comment: Yes, it is global. I've changed the code as you suggested but the result remain the same..

Comment: Is there some function of the MarkerClusterer library I could use?

Comment: You have to call `clusterer.clearMarkers()` additionally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution could be like:

```
var clusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map);

function updateMarkers(dataMarkers) {
    removeAllMarkers();

    if (clusterer) {
        clusterer.clearMarkers();
    }

    // for loop to create markers....

    map.fitBounds();

    clusterer.addMarkers(markers);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With google.maps V3, you can call this method at `idle` event of the map.

```
  refreshMarkerClusterer() {
    if (this.markerClusterer) {
        this.markerClusterer.clearMarkers();
        this.markers.forEach(marker => {
            this.markerClusterer.addMarker(marker);
        });
    }
  },
```

Note that `this.markerClusterer` and `this.markers` are global variables that are already initialized and, I'm using arrow function in foreach to avoid binding `this`.